# Combination of tar and head -1 not working as expected

Tags: bash, pipeline, tar

I am working on a script that needs to decompress a file and then switch to the first folder decompressed using `cd` comment.

What I do is the following:

```
    filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename} | head -1) 
    cd $filename_2
```

And works as expected, but it doesn't decompress all of the files from the tar.gz file not sure why, because if I do:

```
    filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename})
```

It will decompress everything fine, but then I'm not sure how to access to the first folder resulting of the decompression.

I do not understand how a `|` pipeline has effect on a previous command.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `head` finished, it sends a `SIGPIPE` signal to `tar`, causing it to stop. You need to buffer the stdout until tar has finished running, e.g. using `sponge` from moreutils:

```
filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename} | sponge | head -1)
```

If you don't have sponge, `tail` with a high value also generally works:

```
filename_2=$(tar zxvf ${filename} | tail -n 10000000000 | head -1)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for going into detail of why it's happening, kind of new to bash.